# Powershell New-Team cmdlet stops working?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, powershell-cmdlet

I am new to PowerShell. I have a problem with the powerhell CMDLet New-Team. When I use the cmdlet on the script. It won't create a new team in Microsoft Team. The code used:

```
$teamAlias = "mycustomteam01"

$teamDisplayName = "My Custom Team 01"

$teamClassification = "HBI"


$teamAdditionalOwners = @('test@test.unf.edu')

$teamAdditionalMembers = @('test@test.unf.edu')


$teamOwner = $teamAdditionalOwners[0]


$credentials = Get-Credential

Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $credentials

$group = New-Team -MailNickName $teamAlias -DisplayName $teamDisplayName -Visibility "private" -Classification $teamClassification -Owner $teamOwner

foreach ($owner in $teamAdditionalOwners){

if($owner -ne $teamOwner){

    Add-TeamUser -GroupId $group.GroupId -User $member -Role Owner

    }

}

foreach ($member in $teamAdditionalOwners){

    Add-TeamUser -GroupId $group.GroupId -User $member -Role Member

    }
```

error thrown is:

```
New-Team : Error occurred while executing

Code: Request_BadRequest

Message: Property classification has an invalid value.

InnerError:

  RequestId: 4d3ad034-d273-4e26-83ff-86cffc1e4b5b

  DateTimeStamp: 2020-05-14T18:18:54

HttpStatusCode: Request_BadRequest

At line:1 char:10

+ $group = New-Team -MailNickName $teamAlias -DisplayName $teamDisplayN ...

+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Team], ApiException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.ErrorHandling.ApiException,Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.NewTeam
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to create new team?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest version of the PowerShell Teams library?

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow yes, I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs for the [New-Team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/New-Team?view=teams-ps) command, the `-Classification` parameter is "reserved for internal Microsoft use", so that's likely your problem, as per the error message.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the "HBI" classification, out of interest? Perhaps there's another way to do what you're wanting out of that field...

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. Still having issues creating the new team.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. Still having issues creating the new team.I am actually referencing the code from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7l6MZ1CuEg

Comment: if you remove the "classification" parameter, is it giving the same error, or a different one?

Comment: it says that group.GroupdID is null when I remove the "classification" parameter

Comment: That looks like a line further down in the script already. Was the Team actually created?

Comment: No, the team wasn't created

Comment: What happens if you run just that one line, to create the team? Run it with -Verbose and see what output/error is returned